# custom cell for static table view not updating

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, tableview

I have a static table view with 2 cells (in 2 groups).
I have a custom cell (xib) with picture and some data inside.
I've declared through storyboard the cell to be a type of my custom cell and I have a function in my view that sets the  photo of the cell and it's data. The problem is that the cell stays empty. I even tried reload data to the table. Whatam I missing? (I'm new to storyboars and viewes)

the code i'm using:

```
@interface CAUploadDetailsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CAContentCell *currentUploadedFile;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

@end

@implementation CAUploadDetailsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // self.tableView.delegate = self;

    CAContent* content = [[CAContent new] init];
    content.name = @"file.txt";
    content.sizeInBytes = 4444;
    self.currentUploadedFile.item = content;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ExplorerBackground3"]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

when i set the item, it has the following code:

```
- (void)setItem:(id)item
{

        _item = item;
        // Cast content
        CAContent* content = (CAContent *)item;

        self.labelTitle.text = content.name;
        NSString* icon = @"MyIcon";
        // Set icon image
        self.imageIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];

}
```

=== UPDATE (25/1/15)===

i've managed to solve it using cellForRowAtIndexPath, but it feels that this solution is a bit weird (i don't like the code) - is this is how custom cells should be handled? because i need only 1 cell to be custom (i've got 2 cells in my table)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // self.tableView.delegate = self;
    // Customize background
    self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"ExplorerBackground3"].CGImage;

    // Register cell nib
    [self.table registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CAContentCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CAContentCell"];



}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // we should configure only the first cell.
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {

        CAContentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CAContentCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CAContentCell"
                                                 owner:self
                                               options:nil][0];
        }

        CAContent* content = [[CAContent new] init];
        content.name = @"file.txt";
        content.sizeInBytes = 4444;
        cell.item = content;
        return  cell;
    }

    return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to call [tableView reloadData] after set photo? Show your code.

Comment: I tried calling it at viewdidload and still. Empty cell. I'll be at the office tomorrow and post the entire code

Comment: hi, added code sample.